# How can I force an interpolated function to go through a certain point?

Tags: interpolation

Let's take this interpolated function:

`f = ListInterpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}]`

I want to make `1/f'[x]` go through a certain point (x=2, y=1, say). How can I do it?

[image]

The brute force way seems to be generating a list of `1/f'[x]` for several values of $x$, artificially shifting the $x=2$ value to $y=1$, and then generating another interpolation function through the new list - but it seems extremely clunky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As kglr notes in a comment, this is where you realize that you need a [piecewise Hermite interpolant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline). Luckily, the `Interpolation[]` function in *Mathematica* can do this.

```
ff = Interpolation[{{{1}, 1}, {{2}, 2, 1}, {{3}, 3}, {{4}, 5}, {{5}, 8}, {{6}, 5}}];

1/ff'[2]
   1

Plot[ff[x], {x, 1, 6}, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[ColorData[97, 4], AbsolutePointSize[5]], 
                Point[MapIndexed[Append[#2, #1] &, {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}]]}]
```

[image: piecewise Hermite interpolant]

Comment: You additionally need  `InterpolationOrder -> 6 ` to get a smooth derivative curve `Plot[ff'[x], {x, 1, 6}] ` .

Comment: The  OP didn't specify the order of continuity wanted, so I left it at that. Indeed, the `InterpolationOrder` can be increased if wanted.